# Speed up Laravel Eloquent/MySQL query

Tags: mysql, eloquent, relational-database

I have an Eloquent query that is currently taking about **700ms** to run and it will only increase as I add more websites to the user account.  I'm trying to see what the best way to optimize it is so that it can run faster.

I really don't want to save the "results" of my calculations and then just fetch those in a smaller query later because they could update at any moment and that would mean they would not be accurate 100% of the time. Although I am pretty sure that would speed up the query, I don't want to sacrifice accuracy over performance.

This is essentially the raw query that runs:

```
select  *
    from  
      ( SELECT  `positions`.*,
                @rank := IF(@group = keyword_id, @rank+1,
                                   1) as rank_e0686ae02a55b8ad75aec0c7aaec0a21,
                @group := keyword_id as group_e0686ae02a55b8ad75aec0c7aaec0a21
            from  
              ( SELECT  @rank:=0, @group:=0 ) as vars,
            positions
            order by  `keyword_id` asc, `created_at` desc
      ) as positions
    where  `rank_e0686ae02a55b8ad75aec0c7aaec0a21` <= '2'
      and  `positions`.`keyword_id` in ('hundreds of IDs listed here')
```

The query is generated using the solution [mentioned here](https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-n-related-models-per-parent/) with regards to getting N number of relations per record.

I've tried running a simpler query without the N number of relations per record, and it actually ends up being even slower because it's fetching much more data.  So the problem I think is that there are too many `ID`s that are trying to be matched up in the `IN` method of the query.

In my controller I have:

```
$user = auth()->user();
$websites = $user->websitesAndKeywords();
```

In my `User` model:

```
public function websitesAndKeywords() {

        $user = auth()->user();
        $websites = $user->websites()->orderBy('url')->get();

        $websites->load('keywords', 'keywords.latestPositions');

        return $websites;
}
```

I would appreciate any help anyone could provide in helping me speed this thing up.

EDIT: So I think I figured it out.  The problem is the `IN` clause that Laravel uses every time eager loading is used to load relations.  So I need to find a way to do a `JOIN` instead of eager loading.

Essentially need to convert this:

`$websites->load('keywords', 'keywords.latestPositions');`

Into:

```
$websites->load(['keywords' => function($query)
{
    $query->join('positions', 'keywords.id', '=', 'positions.keyword_id');
}]);
```

That doesn't work, so I'm not sure what's the best way to do a `JOIN` on a current collection.  Ideally I would also only fetch the latest N positions too and not all data.

Here are indexes on `positions` table:

[image]

And here is what explain returns for the query:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need, if you don't have it yet, an index `positions(keyword_id)`, or maybe `positions(keyword_id,created_at)`, depending on your data, depending on if you want to keep using "lazy evaluate", and depending on if you want to use the trigger-solution.

And you have to, as Rick suggested, move your `keyword_id in...` into the inner query, as mysql will not be able to optimize it into the subquery since the optimizer doesn't understand that `IF(@group = keyword_id, @rank+1, 1)` will not need the other keywords to work properly.

This should give results for tables with several million rows (if you don't want to retrieve them all in `IN`) in less than 700ms, and might be improved by removing the "lazy evaluate" as Rick also suggested (so you do less table lookups for columns not included in your index), depending on your data.

If you still have troubles, you could however actually precalculate the data without loss of accuracy by using triggers. It will add a (most likely small) overhead to your inserts/updates, so if you insert/update a lot and only query once in a while, you might not want to do it.

For this, you should really use the index `positions (keyword_id`,`created_at`).

Add another table `keywordrank` with the columns `keyword_id, rank, primarykeyofpositionstable`, primary key `keyword_id` and `rank`. You need another table, since in a trigger, mysql can't update other rows in the table you are updating.

Create a trigger that will update these ranks on every insert to your `positions`-table:

```
delimiter $$
create trigger tr_positions_after_insert_updateranks after insert on positions 
for each row
begin
  delete from keywordrank where keyword_id = NEW.keyword_id;
  insert into keywordrank (keyword_id, rank, primarykeyofpositionstable)
  select NEW.keyword_id, ranks.rank, ranks.position_pk
  from  
    (select  NEW.keyword_id, 
             @rank := @rank+1 as rank,
             `positions`.primarykeyofpositionstable as position_pk
     from  
       (SELECT  @rank:=0, @group:=0 ) as vars,
       positions
     where `positions`.keyword_id = NEW.keyword_id
     order by `keyword_id` asc, `created_at` desc
    ) as ranks
    where  ranks.rank <= 2;
end$$
delimiter ;
```

If you want to be able to update or delete the entries (or to be safe if you do it at one time, so it might be a good idea anyway), add the same as an `update`/`delete`-trigger, just do it for both `old.keyword_id` and `new.keyword_id` - and you might want to put the code into a procedure to reuse it then. E.g. create a procedure `fctname(kwid int)`, put the whole trigger code in it but replace all `NEW.keyword_id` with `kwid` and then just call `fctname(new.keyword_id)` for `insert`, `fctname(new.keyword_id)` and `fctname(old.keyword_id)` for `update` and `fctname(old.keyword_id)` for `delete`.

You need to init that table one time (and if you e.g. decide you may need more ranks or another order), you can use any version of your code, e.g.

```
delete from keywordrank;

insert into keywordrank (keyword_id, rank, primarykeyofpositionstable)
select ranks.keyword_id, ranks.rank, ranks.position_pk
from  
  ( SELECT  `positions`.primarykeyofpositionstable as position_pk,
             @rank := IF(@group = keyword_id, @rank+1,
                                   1) as rank,
             @group := keyword_id as keyword_id
            from  
              ( SELECT  @rank:=0, @group:=0 ) as vars,
            positions
            order by  `keyword_id` asc, `created_at` desc
      ) as ranks
    where  ranks.rank <= 2;
```

You can put both the trigger(s) and the init in your migration files (without the delimiter).

You then can just use a join to get your desired rows.

**Update** The code without trigger, using index on `(keyword_id, created_at)`. You can calculate the inner query completely from the index and then only look up the found ids in the tabledata. It depends on the number of rows in your result (in relation to your whole table), how much of an effect removing the lazy evaluate will have.

```
select positions.*, poslist.rank, poslist.group
from positions
join
  ( SELECT  `positions`.id,
            @rank := IF(@group = keyword_id, @rank+1,
                               1) as rank,
            @group := keyword_id as group 
        from  
          ( SELECT  @rank:=0, @group:=0 ) as vars,
        positions
        where `positions`.`keyword_id` in ('hundreds of IDs listed here')
        order by  `keyword_id` asc, `created_at` desc
  ) as poslist
  on positions.id = poslist.id
  where poslist.rank <= 2;
```

Check `explain` if it actually uses the correct index `(keyword_id, created_at)`. If that is not fast enough, you should try the trigger solution. (Or add the new `explain`-output and `show profile`-output to let us have a deeper look.)

Comment: I do have a lot of inserts so as you mentioned, it's probably not a good idea to do triggers.  As far as moving the `where in` to the inner query, I've done that but have not seen any performance improvements. I don't know if it's because I don't have millions of records, but from my local dev, I'm getting around `35-43ms` with `positions` table containing about 5k rows.  Does that sound good?  It's still kinda slow to me.  Is there no better solution to the `where in` clause?  It just seems that's the slow part here because there's too many IDs to look up.

Comment: @zen Assuming you have an index (you should check that!), the time should not scale that much with the number of rows, but with the number of ids in your `where in` clause (they have to processed, but will then be a direct lookup - assuming an index, no lazy evaluate and if it's not a big % of all rows). Can you add the `Explain`-output (just write explain directly infront of the first select and run it), and, to verify your indexes, `show indexes from positions;`; and maybe the profiling output: `set @@profiling=1; do your select query; show profile; showprofiles; set @@profiling=0;`.

Comment: I added images of what indexes and explain shows. The profiling part did not work (I'm using phpmyadmin). Can you tell me if you see anything wrong?  BTW that query returns `476 rows` in `0.0450 seconds`, and there are total 5793 rows in `positions`.

Comment: @zen well, you have no index on `keyword_id`. Add it. (That was my first sentence in my answer, and I meant it!). And since you are testing anyway, add an index `(keyword_id, created_at)`. Then replace `positions.*` by `positions.id` just to see if it makes a difference (with the second index, it should). The time you get now should be close to the time you will get on your server for the same query but more rows. And finally you might want to rewrite the `where in` e.g like `where keyword_id in ('9','10') or (keyword_id >= 22 and keyword_id <= 131)` (you might know the logic behind your ids).

Comment: Whoops sorry.  I created the additional indexes, one for just `keyword_id` and other for `keyword_id, created_at`.  Unfortunately that did not affect execution time at all.  But once I changed the `positions.*` to `positions.id` that did.  It took time from around `0.0450 seconds` to only `0.0065 seconds`.  Also, I can't change the `where in` to use the logic because there won't be any.  It looks like there is now because I'm the only user on the dev server, but in prod, they'll all be pretty random.  So now is there a way to keep this performance while adding additional columns?

Comment: @zen added the code to my answer. If it's still not fast enough, there isn't much more potential without adjusting your server options, adding more ram or bying a faster hdd. Then you should try the triggers - I didn't want to scare you away from them. They will add an overhead to each insert, but probably only in the order of 0.0005s on your dev machine. Unless you do more than some 100 inserts or updates on your table per second, it shouldn't be a real concern. Though it would obviously be better if the non-trigger solution would work good enough.)

Comment: Thanks.  I'll mark this answer since it has so much useful info but you're right I will probably just need to look into upgrading server instead and test various server configurations too.

Answer (score 0):

The code for finding the "top 2 in each grouping" is the best I have ever seen.  It is essentially the same as what I have in [my blog on such](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max).

However, there are two other things that we *may* be able to improve on.

- Move `keyword_id in...` from the outer query to the inner.  I assume you have an index starting with `keyword_id`?
- "Lazy evaluate".  That is, instead of doing `SELECT positions.*, ...`, do only `SELECT id, ...` where `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of `positions`.  Then, in the outer query, `JOIN` back to `positions` to get the rest of the columns.  With out seeing `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and knowing what percentage of the table in in the `IN` list, I can't be sure that this will help much.

Comment: I think the culprit in my query is the `WHERE IN` clause that contains hundreds of IDs.  The `WHERE IN` just seems really slow when it comes to that many IDs.  I'm kinda looking to replace that with a join as it might be faster, but not sure how to do it in Eloquent as mentioned above.

Comment: Also, `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be about 70% of _available_ RAM.